# Reference Pandas dataframe column headers from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe, df with columns headers xx, yy, zz, aaa

I then have lists

```
A=['xx']
B=['yy']
C=['zz']
```

can I reference these headers from this dictionary?

```
dic={'key1':['A','B'],
key2: ['C','D']}

df[dic[key1[0]]]
```

giving the output of just column xx?

```
   xx
0  44
1  44
2  44
3  33
```

Comment: what’s in the lists? column names as strings?

Comment: sorry yes, strings

Comment: this is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do

Comment: I'm getting an error saying ''A" is not a column in df, when really I'm trying to pull 'xx' from the list A

Comment: This error is because you are passing the name of the list as a string and not as the name A itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just pass the lists itself into the dictionary instead of a string with the name of the list. Also you need to modify the call of your dictionary (see Explanation below). Try this:

```
dic={'key1':[A,B], 'key2': [C,D]}
col = df[dic['key1'][0][0]]
print(col)
```

**Explanation:**

Your goal is to get the dataframe column `df['xx']`. To get the `'xx'` from the dictionary you need to get the value of the desired key in the dictionary. There was a typo in your call, as your key is a string, so you you need to write `dic['key1']`. This will return you the list `[['xx'],['yy']]` which returns 2 sublists. From this list you need to get the first sublist, which has index `[0]`. So, `dic['key1'][0]` will give you the sublist `['xx']`. But as this is also a list and you actually want the first element of it, you again have to use the index `[0]`. Hence, the call  `dic['key1'][0][0]` will give you the desired string `'xx'`.

Remark: If `A` really only contains a list with one single element, I recommend not to use a list and just write `A = 'xx'`. You can then save the second `[0]` in call of the dictionary and the call of the dataframe column will be like: `df[dic['key1'][0]]`